# What is the load on the system

Tags: linux

I have a Red hat server where I can see the load average on the system is 23 24 23 (1min 5min 15min) using the top command. And i can see in /proc/cpuinfo there are 24 processors entry (0-23). But in each processor entry the cpu cores value is 6 and in each processor entry the physical id is either 1 or 0.
I want to know if my system is overloaded. Can anyone please tell me.

Comment: as long as load average is greater than 1 technically your system is overloaded I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a system with two processors, each with 6 cores. Each of the cores can likely run hyperthread => 2 x 6 x 2 = 24. In `/proc/cpuinfo`, `top` etc, you will see each hyperthread: that's the number of parallel processes or threads that your hardware can run.

The quick answer is that your system is probably not overloaded and that it processes a relatively stable amount of work over time (as the 1, 5 and 15 minute values are about the same). A rule of thumb is that the load average value should stay below the number of hyperthreads -- this is not, however, exactly true.

You'll find a more in-depth discussion here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303699/how-is-the-load-average-interpreted-in-top-output-is-it-the-same-for-all-di

and here:

https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-on-unix-linux

and perhaps here:

https://linuxhint.com/load_average_linux/

However, please keep in mind that load average does not tell you everything about your system -- though it is usually a pretty good indicator in my experience.  You'd have to check many other factors to determine overloadedness, like memory pressure, I/O wait times, I/O bandwidth utilization. It also depends on what kind of processing the system is performing.